# Deployment Practice: Separately a server for background works in node js

Tags: node.js, performance, deployment, server, devops

I have a Node.js app that utilizes BullMQ, a queue manager for background jobs. My server is becoming slow due to heavy computations of these background jobs. I use Elastic Beanstalk for deployment.

I'm planning to allocate a separate server just for background jobs. Are there any best practices that I should follow? Since the code will be the same on both servers, how can I identify the server for handling requests and the server for background jobs (my idea is to use environment variables)? Is there a better way?